# Selecting values from database by linking tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am looking for an efficient way to select values from multiple tables in my MySQL database, *based* off a "super" value from the main table.

For example the structure may be as such:

```
widgets         {id, widgetType, userId, pageId}
widgets_text    {parentId, `value`, style}
widgets_images  {parentId, src, link}
```

In this example above, the parentId in widgets_text and widgets_images is the "Id" in the table *widgets*

If I wanted to select ALL text and image widgets based off an entered Page id (pageId), how would I create a query for this?

Thanks in advance.

(Also I might add, if I wanted to do an *insert* statement for a new image [for example], how would I go about doing that?)

EDIT:
Example of what I am doing at the moment:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    widgets w
    INNER JOIN widgets_text wt ON wt.parentId = w.id
    INNER JOIN widgets_images wi ON wi.parentId = wt.parentId;
```

^^ separate query must be run for each sub-table.

Comment: Show some efforts along with the possible inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Have a look at join to learn how to "link" tables. Try to write your own query and come back here to show your efforts and your issue

Comment: my apologies guys, I'll update the post in a second :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join the text and images table you could use the following statement where X is your entered pageID

```
select *
from widgets w
left join widgets_text wt on (wt.parentId = w.id)
left join widgets_images wi on (wi.parentId = w.id)
where w.pageId = X;
```

I'm using `LEFT JOIN` because from your questions it's not clear if these tables will defenitly have rows regarding to a widget row

Comment: Yeah they would definitely have a row in either the text or images table but not both.

Comment: Then left join is the way to go as it "tries" to grab a row from the text/images tables and return the values if it finds an entry or NULL if not for each table. If you use inner join then you will get no result if there's not a row in both tables.

Comment: Thanks. With the code you provided, (where you have both the left joins after one another), is it going to attempt to left join from BOTH tables or just one of them?

Comment: it tries to join each table individualy. let's say you have a widgets record and an text record. then the fields of widges and the text table will be filled with the matching values, the fields of the image table will be null, see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Just thought i'd let you know I ended up doing quite a few changes:
`SELECT * FROM widgets w LEFT JOIN widgets_text wt ON (wt.parent_id = w.id) LEFT JOIN widgets_images wi ON (wi.parent_id = w.id) WHERE w.site_id = :siteid AND w.page_id = :pageid AND w.user_id = :userid AND (w.id = wi.parent_id) OR (w.id = wt.parent_id)`
because it was returning the `widget` even if a `widget_image` (etc) did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT widgets.*,widgets_text.*,widgets_images.*
FROM widgets
INNER JOIN widgets_text on widgets_text.parentId = widgets.id
INNER JOIN widgets_images on widgets_images.parentId = widgets.id
WHERE widgets.pageId = '".$page_value."'
```

Use Inner Join